# porque sucede esto? que debo reparar en mi codigo?

Tags: javascript, formularios, consola, nodemailer

dessarrolle un formulario con ayuda de chatgpt
que al desplegarlo de manera local funciona pero al desplegarlo en mi host de 000webhost no funciona este es el error de consola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
me pueden dar una reseña para poder mejorarlo y lograr hacerlo andar?

Comment: Debes [edit] y agregar el código como texto

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_: [no todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Además dale un título descriptivo a tu pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: eso es `node.js` y por lo que lei ese dominio que indicas solo eso es para `php`

Comment: En cualquier caso un formulario de contacto es una mala idea, ante cualquier error no te van a llegar los correos (oportunidades de negocio desaprovechadas), no conozco a alguna persona que le guste usarlo, te va a llenar el correo de SPAM porque hay bots que andan buscando estos formularios, son fuente principal de hackeos. Mejor dejas tu correo y ya, que todo el mundo sabe envía un correo. Esto de los formularios de contacto viene de la época en que habían muchas personas que no tenían correo, cosa que no aplica.

Comment: En serio ahora les permiten hacer la tarea con ayudas de la IA?? WOW. @Yussef los formularios de contacto están en la mayoría de sitios formales, si son o no vulnerables depende del desarrollador pero que todas las web los tienen, es un hecho.

Comment: @Yussef, cómo un formulario de contacto puede ser una "mala idea"?

Comment: @MauricioContreras No entiendo la pregunta, los motivos de mi opinión lo señalé en el mismo comentario